# 'make installdeps' fails with Net::FTP-related error

Tags: perl

I am writing Catalyst application which uses Module::Install for module building. I keep all project-related modules in separate directory with local::lib:

```
eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/work/projects/freevideo)
```

Recently I've moved to amd64 environment, and 'make installdeps' stopped working:

```
nikita@freevideo-dev:~/fv$ make installdeps
/usr/bin/perl "-Iinc" Makefile.PL --config= \
--installdeps=Text::Table,0,Catalyst::Log::Log4perl,1.04,\
    Catalyst::Plugin::Session,0,Catalyst::Plugin::Session::State::Cookie,0,\
    Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::FastMmap,0,Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication,0,\
    Catalyst::Plugin::Authorization::Roles,0,Catalyst::Plugin::Unicode,0,\
    Catalyst::Plugin::SmartURI,0,Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema,0.5,\
    Catalyst::View::JSON,0.33,Catalyst::View::TT,0.37,\
    Template::Plugin::ListUtil,0.02,Template::Stash::ForceUTF8,0.03,\
    Encode,2.43,DateTime,0.70,DateTime::Format::MySQL,0.04,\
    Mail::RFC822::Address,0.3,Digest::MD5,2.51,Data::Dumper,2.131,DBIx::Class,0.08194
include /home/nikita/work/projects/freevideo/FreeVideo/inc/Module/Install.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Metadata.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Base.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Makefile.pm
Cannot determine perl version info from lib/FV.pm
Cannot determine license info from lib/FV.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Catalyst.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Include.pm
include inc/File/Copy/Recursive.pm
*** Module::Install::Catalyst
Please run "make catalyst_par" to create the PAR package!
*** Module::Install::Catalyst finished.
include inc/Module/Install/Scripts.pm
include inc/Module/Install/AutoInstall.pm
include inc/Module/AutoInstall.pm
*** Installing dependencies...
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at \
    /usr/share/perl/5.10/Net/FTP/dataconn.pm line 54.
Compilation failed in require at \
    /usr/share/perl5/Module/Install/AutoInstall.pm line 37.
make: *** [installdeps] Error 111
```

Here's my Makefile.PL:

```
# IMPORTANT: if you delete this file your app will not work as
# expected.  you have been warned
use inc::Module::Install;
use strict;
use warnings;

name 'FV';
all_from 'lib/FV.pm';

requires 'Moose';               # Moose is required for Catalyst

# Catalyst components
requires 'Catalyst::Runtime' => '5.7015';
requires 'Catalyst::Log::Log4perl' => '1.04';
requires 'Catalyst::Plugin::ConfigLoader';
requires 'Catalyst::Plugin::Static::Simple';
requires 'Catalyst::Plugin::Session';
requires 'Catalyst::Plugin::Session::State::Cookie';
requires 'Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::FastMmap';
requires 'Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication';
requires 'Catalyst::Plugin::Authorization::Roles';
requires 'Catalyst::Plugin::Unicode';
requires 'Catalyst::Plugin::SmartURI';
requires 'Catalyst::Action::RenderView';
requires 'Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema' => '0.5';
requires 'Catalyst::View::JSON' => '0.33';
requires 'Catalyst::View::TT' => '0.37';

# pragmas
requires 'parent';
requires 'utf8'    => '1.07';
requires 'feature' => '1.13';

requires 'Config::General'; # This should reflect the config file format you've chosen
                 # See Catalyst::Plugin::ConfigLoader for supported formats

# Template Toolkit
requires 'Template' => '2.22';
requires 'Template::Plugin::ListUtil' => '0.02';
requires 'Template::Stash::ForceUTF8' => '0.03';

# other
requires 'POSIX' => '1.17';
requires 'Exporter' => '5.63';
requires 'Encode' => '2.43';
requires 'Data::GUID' => '0.046';
requires 'DateTime' => '0.70';
requires 'DateTime::Format::MySQL' => '0.04';
requires 'Mail::RFC822::Address' => '0.3';
requires 'Digest::MD5' => '2.51';
requires 'Data::Dumper' => '2.131';
requires 'File::Copy' => '2.14';
requires 'DBIx::Class' => '0.08194';

test_requires 'Test::More';
test_requires 'Test::Exception';
test_requires 'Text::Table';

catalyst;

install_script glob('script/*.pl');
auto_install;
WriteAll;
```

Everything runs on Ubuntu Natty amd64. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: **Solved!** CPANPLUS had FTP mirrors written in its configuration, and I was too lazy to properly configure my ftp proxy. After replacing all ftp mirrors with http dependencies were successfully installed.

Comment: Hi Nikita, when you solve your own question, you are supposed to put it in the **answer textarea** below and also **accept** it with the ✔ checkmark. This way, this question will not show up anymore in the unanswered question list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!** CPANPLUS had FTP mirrors written in its configuration, and I was too lazy to properly configure my ftp proxy. After replacing all ftp mirrors with http dependencies were successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message  : Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/Net/FTP/dataconn.pm line 54.

From reading Nikita answer, I made these changes to fix it:

1. sudo vim ~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm
2. in the 'urllist' line: replace ftp by http